# What is the procedure for typing cangjie here?

Tags: characters, cantonese, radicals, input-methods, character-components

I've been typing Mandarin with pinyin input for years and have never found it terribly difficult to learn. However, I am finding that when I need to use website and type Cantonese expressions, I find it burdensome to try to find the appropriate character in Mandarin pinyin, so I'm trying to learn the cangjie input instead.

I am currently looking at [this website on how to learn](https://how-to.fandom.com/wiki/How_to_learn_to_type_in_Chinese_with_Cangjie_input_method) and the diagrams and instructions are a bit confusing to me. For example, it looks like they are building characters from radicals here, but the construction seems odd:

[image]

Here it seems they are using logographemes instead of the actual radicals. The bottom diagram is even more confusing because its not immediately clear to me what 卜 is doing to create 辶. What is the proper way of typing the characters if the keys themselves are radicals?

Comment: the cantonese speech recognition is excellent on iphone, or mac os machine. next is, handwriting recognition, also quite good, imo 

Comment: I have no issues with handwriting characters, but I don't have that option for using my laptop, hence my interest.

Comment: using any input method for chinese is, . . . errrr, adding difficulty in the learning. if one can, avoid it; life is short, and knowledge is so immense 

Comment: Well true but there is no avoiding it when typing on a keyboard haha

Comment: 卜 is assigned to create 辶. You have to memorize each key's corresponding output such as typing 人&大 which output to 攵. (As you can see, typing 大 outputs 乂) And I'm not sure what you mean by typing the characters if the keys themselves are radicals. FYI I have been using Cangjie as my primary typing method and I speak Cantonese.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check out [this site](https://www.hkcards.com/cj/article-menu.html) for ChangJie input method.

Here is a diagram of key->character fragment correspondence from the aforementioned site.

Once you have memorized the table, the next important thing is to know how to break up a character into Cangjie letters. The rule is from top to down, left to right. This is [the page](https://www.hkcards.com/cj/article-extraction-principle.html) that explains the rules. Once you familiarize yourself with the rule on that page, follow the link at the bottom of the page for more rules.

明=日+月
門=日+弓
昌=日+日
旱=日+一+十
巴=日+山
免=弓+日+竹+山

[image]

Comment: An example will help. The OP is confused about how to utilize the table - type in the English letter to bring up the corresponding Chinese building characters and select.

Comment: Yeah if you could edit your answer to provide some examples that would be great

Comment: @Shawn Hemelstrand I have edited the answer to provide few examples on how to construct a character using Cangjie letters. However, few examples can' cover all the rules of how to break up a character into Cangjie letters. You'd better read the links for a full explanation of the rules.

Comment: Thanks that is helpful